# If Statement not Working right

Tags: c#, if-statement, operators

I need some help with some operators in the If statement...

I am running a code like this

```
if (statement.Contains("weather") &&
    (
        statement.Contains("what") || statement.Contains("how")
    )
   )
{
    statement = ("It's " + Weather.Get_Weather("condition") + " outside");
}
```

but it's not working... can any one help me with this, because I cannot find any mistake in this code and I don't even have that much experience with this type of operators like `||` and `&&` because I can use `If Statements` inside `If Statements`.

And I want the statement to have Weather and What or How so I can confirm It's a Question, Or the user is asking for the weather...
You can Also gimme more ideas on this...

`'how is the weather'` this is not going through the `If statement`
it contains How and weather that's enough...

I am Really Sorry for my Question, It was My Problem I did not know that `Contains()` is Case-Sensitive...

Comment: What is Wheater for a class? What doesn't work? Give us more information to help you!

Comment: Your statement looks right, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Show us, what actually happen to statement variable before if statement, maybe problem lies there

Comment: What is the value of `statement` that isn't working?  Maybe you need case insensitive search?

Comment: Define 'it's not working'. Are you getting an error? Is the wrong statement being shown? What?

Comment: Also, try to use `ToLower().Contains("weather")`

Comment: Updated `'how is the weather' this is not going through the If statement it contains How and weather that's enough...`

Comment: 'how is the weather' this is not going through the If statement it contains How and weather that's enough...   -> Is your test supposed to be case insensitive?

Comment: @vc74 Nope it should not be

Comment: @RajaBilal Then 'how is the weather'.Contains('How') is going to return false

Comment: It is going through the if statement, and it sets the `statement`. How about you change it to `Console.WriteLine` and see

Comment: I tested, and it works. Try apply a lowercase function on your 'statement' string.

Comment: What is the exact statement? You say it's 'how is the weather', but then say it contains 'How' and 'weather', which should be enough. The statement does NOT contain 'How', it contains 'how'. As for 'weather' this will only work if the statement also contains 'what', which it doesn't. Smells like a case sensitivity issue to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the statement you're testing is actually 'How is the weather' then your `if statement` is working as expected. Your checks are seeing if the statement contains 'weather' and 'what' OR contains the word 'how' (note the lower case).

As your phrase doesn't contain the word 'what' the first check (for the words 'weather' AND 'what') will be false. Also, as the word 'How' starts with a capital 'H' it won't match against 'how', so will also return false and therefore not enter the `if statement`.

If you want your search to be case insensitive then you will need to consider the language as well, as words all in upper case in some languages mean different things to the same word in all lower case. Here's a similar [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring), accepted answer detailed below for completeness:

> To test if the string paragraph contains the string word (thanks
>   @QuarterMeister) culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(paragraph, word,
>   CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0
>
> Where culture is the instance of CultureInfo describing the language
>   that the text is written in.
>
> This solution is transparent about the definition of
>   case-insensitivity, which is language dependent. For example, the
>   English language uses the characters I and i for the upper and lower
>   case versions of the ninth letter, whereas the Turkish language uses
>   these characters for the eleventh and twelfth letters of its 29
>   letter-long alphabet. The Turkish upper case version of 'i' is the
>   unfamiliar character 'İ'.
>
> Thus the strings tin and TIN are the same word in English, but
>   different words in Turkish. As I understand, one means 'spirit' and
>   the other is an onomatopoeia word. (Turks, please correct me if I'm
>   wrong, or suggest a better example)
>
> To summarise, you can only answer the question 'are these two strings
>   the same but in different cases' if you know what language the text is
>   in. If you don't know, you'll have to take a punt. Given English's
>   hegemony in software, you should probably resort to
>   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, because it'll be wrong in familiar ways.

Comment: I was doing it wrong I changed my use of this If statement I mean it was first just `if (statement.Contains("weather"))` but then I added these What and How but forgot to change the variable `statement` you should also have noticed it xD, But it is okay I figured it out...